# How can I add tags or groups in Apple Contacts?

Tags: macos, ios, contacts, contacts.app

I have people in my address book, but I want to organize them by topic.

Like Work or Office or Friends or well, you get it.

How can I do that on the desktop? I'm assuming its using the group feature, but I can't figure out how to add someone to a group.

How can I do that on my iPhone? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS**

This is not presently possible on iOS, but you can do this via the use of third party apps such as [Groups](https://qbix.com/groups).

**macOS**

This **is** possible on macOS. You don't specify what version of macOS you're using, but below is the basic process:

1. Open the Contacts app
2. Click the Add button
3. Select the New Group option
4. Give your new group a name
5. Click on All Contacts
6. Select the contacts you want to add to the new group
7. Now *drag* these contacts to the new group

NOTES:

- You can also create a group by first selecting the contacts you want to be a part of the group (you do this by keeping the <kbd>command</kbd> key down and clicking on the contacts you want) and then going to File > New Group From Selection.
- To see any groups that a contact is part of, you can click on the contact and then press the <kbd>option</kbd> key.
- You can actually create an advanced group (known as [Smart Groups](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22766?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)) that will automatically add or remove contacts based on rules you create.

Answer (score 1):

In the **macOS Contacts** app, you can create a new Group by either going into **File** → **New Group** or pressing <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>.

To add a contact to that group, simply drag them from the main list to the group in the left side-pane. If that pane is hidden, you may make it visible by going into **View** → **Show Groups** or pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>.

As of iOS 10.3, it is not possible to manipulate groups in the **iOS Contacts** app, only filter by groups.

You can perform these operations using the web apps at iCloud.com, although doing so using **Safari for iOS** is very difficult.